# Creating function that inputs a vector and numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, function, vector

My function does not work. Here's the data frame (it is bigger than this, but the rest is irrelevant to this function):

`df <- data.frame(TypesOfTouch = c("Hug","Handshake","Kiss"))`

And the vector I will use to check if it matches with the data frame and convert to their respective numerics:

`Vec <- c("Stroke","Caress","Hug")`

So I wrote this function:

```
Converter <- function(VectorInp,Col){
 for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (is.element(df[i,Col],VectorInp)){
   df[i,Col] <- which(VectorInp == df[i,Col])
  }
 }

Converter(Vec,1)
```

The weird thing is that the code works when it is not applied to a function as shown above. Therefore, I was wondering if the problem could be that it couldn't input a vector. However, it was still a vector as input (checked using `(~is.vector(VectorInp))`.

For reference, this code works and does the same (but it is not a function):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
 if (is.element(df[i,1],Vec)){
  df[i,1] <- which(Vec == df[i,1])
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please test your code before posting. When I run the first line of your code I get "Error: unexpected symbol in "df <- data.frame(Types of"" because `Types of touch` is not a valid R column name. What do you want the result to be. Your for loop overwrites your original data so if you run it a second time, the results change.

Comment: Thanks, that's good feedback. I'll be sure to do that in the future. I want the code to alter the dataframe "df" every time it loops through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. The reason you have no output is, that your function doesn't `return` something. Currently you didn't include a command that allows the modified data frame to leave the function scope.

So you may want to do:

```
Converter <- function(VectorInp, Col) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (is.element(df[i, Col], VectorInp)) {
      df[i, Col] <- which(VectorInp == df[i, Col])
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

  
Converter(Vec, 1)
#        Type
# 1         3
# 2 Handshake
# 3      Kiss
```

Instead of `return(df)` you may also briefly write just `df`.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- data.frame(Type = c("Hug", "Handshake", "Kiss"))
Vec <- c("Stroke", "Caress", "Hug")
```